# Java application not completing

Tags: java, swing, exe

Was trying to get a JFrame added to see if it would help with using launch4j to convert a small jar file to an .exe.  I wrote a short program to help sort HPLC data at work and want to make it just a simple point and click.

It works when I run it from the command line `java KFile` and the JFileChooser lets me choose directories for the script to work on.  When I converted it to the .exe, the `JFileChooser` never rendered and the .exe closes.

I read that I might need a JFrame parent and so I created a JFrame, but now the script hangs before completion as if waiting for the frame to close. I'm pretty new to java, so I'm not sure how I to resolve this issue.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;



public class KFile extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path currPath = Paths.get("");
        String currDir = currPath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        System.out.println(currDir);


        File dataDir = chooseDir("open");
        File destDir = chooseDir("save");


        if(!destDir.exists()) {

            try {
                destDir.mkdir();
            }
            catch (SecurityException se) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't make directory!");
            }

        }
        int n = 0;
        if(dataDir.exists()) {
            Collection<Path> allDir  = new ArrayList<Path>();
            try {
                addTree(dataDir.toPath(),allDir);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error with scanning");
            }
            for( Path thisPath : allDir ) {
                if(thisPath.toString().contains("Report.pdf")) {
                    Path thisDir = thisPath.getParent();
                    File f = new File(thisDir.toString(), "\\Report.txt");
                    n = n + 1;
                    String fileName = "Report " + n + ".pdf";
                    try {
                        fileName = parseName(f);
                        System.out.println(fileName);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    File thisFile = new File(destDir + "\\" + fileName);

                    try {
                        copyFile(thisPath.toFile(),thisFile);
                    } catch ( IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }


    public static boolean copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
        //create file if it doesn't exist.
        if(!destFile.exists()) {
            destFile.createNewFile();           
        }

        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        }
        finally {
            if(source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if(destination != null) {
                destination.close();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static File chooseDir(String s) {

        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("HPLC Data Transfer");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        File currDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents");

        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(currDir);

        int choice = 0;
        if (s.equals("save")) {
            choice = chooser.showSaveDialog(myFrame);
        } else {
            choice = chooser.showOpenDialog(myFrame);
        }

        myFrame.setVisible(false);
        myFrame.removeAll();
        if(choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("You chose to open: " + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
            return chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
        return new File("");
    }

    static String parseName(File f) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-16"));

        int lnCnt = 32;
        String[] fileData = new String[lnCnt];

        for (int i = 0; i < lnCnt; i++) {
            fileData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
        fileData[1] = fileData[1].replace("\uFEFF","");
        String name = fileData[1].substring(13) + ".pdf";

        textReader.close();
        return name;
    }

    static void addTree(Path directory, final Collection<Path> all)
        throws IOException {
    Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
                throws IOException {
            all.add(file);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing

```
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

to

```
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

and then call

```
myFrame.dispose();
```

to terminate the `JFrame`.
Since [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) says `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` terminates the whole program using `System.exit();` I'm not sure if that's the problem that is stopping your application but I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just called `setVisible(false)` when dealing with your JFrame. That just hides your JFrame, it doesn't get rid of it. If you want to get rid of your frame entirely (and all of its resources), call `myFrame.dispose();`